# Codeigniter mod rewrite in CentOS

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, centos

I am trying to set up my project (built in Codeigniter) in Apache/2.0.52 (CentOS) Server.

Everything works perfectly on my local XAMPP server but on the live server, when i try to access pages like myproject.com/agents, it shows

'The requested URL /home/virtual/site777/somefolder/var/www/html/index.php/agents was not found on this server.'

The rewrite rule that I've got at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(assets|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have following settings in my application/config.php file

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Just to be clear, is `/home/virtual/site777/somefolder/var/www/html/` a directory which is specified in `httpd.conf`. If you just put a test `index.html` in that directory, can you access that?

Comment: @danneth The above directory is specified in httpd.conf. There is no problem in accessing the index page. My problem is accessing other pages like i mentioned above. I can even access those page using the structure index.php/agents but i can't access when i removed index.php from url. In my localhost, it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my CentOS I only have this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|resources)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

But my site resides in `/var/www/html`. I am by no means an expert on Apache, but perhaps you need to set the

```
RewriteBase /home/virtual/site777/somefolder/var/www/html/
```

As well

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for viewing and answering my question.

I was able to solve my problem using RewriteBase in htaccess file.

Answer (score -1):

you have to enable url rewriting module of apache.